# How to inherit javascript from core OpenERP 6.1

Tags: javascript, inheritance, odoo

I made some changes in my core module to hide some buttons using javascript.
I put this code below in my `view_list_editable.js`

```
openerp.web.ListView.include({
  start: function() {
    var self = this;
    var ret = this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    var res_model = this.dataset.model;
    if ($.inArray(res_model, ['inno.open.lab.report']) != -1) {
      self.options.addable = false; /* create button */
      self.options.deletable = false; /* delete button */
    };
    return ret;
  },
});
```

and it works.
But when I try to inherit it, by put it doesn't work at all
I did it like this

1. I make a new javascript file that contain this code below:

   instance.web.ListView = instance.web.ListView.extend({
       start: function() {
           var self = this;
           var ret = this._super.apply(this, arguments);
           var res_model = this.dataset.model;
           if ($.inArray(res_model, ['inno.open.lab.report']) != -1) {
               self.options.addable = false; /* create button */
               self.options.deletable = false; /* delete button */
           };
           return ret;
       },
   });
2. I put it my_module/static/src/js
3. I also add javascript in terp like this:

   `'js' : ['static/src/js/view_list_editable.js',],`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to have `'web'` in the dependencies section of terp as well:

```
'depends': [
         'web',
         ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are doing write put there is still one more step to do.

Add this below code in your views/xml file at top.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <template id="assets_backend" name="your-module-name" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/module-ame/static/src/js/view_list_editable.js"></script>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Try this one.!